# Git rebase & merge problems with symbolic links

Tags: git, git-merge, symlink, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

During a `git rebase` or `git merge`, symbolic links seem to be converted to plain files.

I ran into the following problem with symbolic links when running `git rebase master` on a branch.

First, some background:

- master did not contain the symbolic links in question, but did contains all the targets of the symbolic links.
- The symbolic links in question were all added to the branch in one commit.

During the rebase, I got a "`CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ...`" for each of the symbolic links. When I did a `git ls-files --stage` on each supposed symbolic link, it showed the mode as 100644 (i.e. a plain file, not a symbolic link). I wrote a simple shell script to replace each of these text files with the required symbolic link, added them to the index and continued with the rebase.

A while back I had noticed a set of symbolic links I'd added on a previous previous branch had morphed into plain text files on master, each containing just the path of what had previously been the link's target; I suspected at the time that the change had occurred during the merge from the branch to master, and now I'm more sure.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to get Git to better handle symbolic links during a merge?
2. If `git rebase` or `git merge` throws up conflicts and changes symbolic links to plain files, is there a better way to fix the problem than deleting each file and recreating the symbolic link?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to get Git to better handle symbolic links during a merge?

Not really, no.  If the two added files have the *same* content, Git does not call that a conflict at all (I just tested this), and the merge succeeds.

Ultimately, the problem is that a symbolic link *is* a data file, with the data being the target of the link, which is all just one line (without a terminating newline!).  A sufficiently link-y OS, however, stores this data specially and can only access it specially.  (Windows is generally *not* sufficently link-y and stores it as a plain text file instead.)  So, suppose two symlinks in two to-be-merged files that are in two commits both differ from the original symlink in the original commit:

```
merge base: file foo should be a symlink to bar/baz
--ours:     file foo should be a symlink to our/name
--theirs:   file foo should be a symlink to different/path
```

Since it's all a single line, Git cannot merge these two changes, which both change the same source line—line 1 being the *only* line—of the merge-base file.  You must merge them manually.

(In your case, there's no stage 1 entry at all, just stages 2 and 3, hence an "add/add conflict", which is what I call a *high level* conflict that never goes into the low-level file-merge code.  The description below is intended more for low-level conflict cases—which can also occur, and is where `-X ours` or `-X theirs` can work.  For high level conflicts, Git never gets into the `-X`-handling code.)

> When I did a `git ls-files --stage` on each supposed symbolic link, it showed the mode as 100644 (i.e. a plain file, not a symbolic link).

That's arguably a bug.  I will note that when I tried this as an experiment, that's not what I got:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 79f977c119cd6951428b04565177cb4e53dd4bc3 0       README
100644 fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92 0       newfile
120000 1b407f24bddc88f87d93302f462251bf881acbc9 2       newlink
120000 1de565933b05f74c75ff9a6520af5f9f8a5a2f1d 3       newlink
```

Note the `mode 120000` lines here.  The symlink remains a symlink in my work-tree, too:

```
$ ls -l newlink
lrwxr-xr-x  1 torek  torek   9 Feb  5 00:55 newlink -> newtarget
```

Had a third (different) symlink existed in the merge base, I'm not sure Git would keep my work-tree file as a symlink.

(I expect `git mergetool` winds up extracting these two into plain files:

```
$ git checkout-index --temp --stage 2 newlink
.merge_link_OzyiFR      newlink
```

so if you're using `git mergetool`, it's `git mergetool`'s fault here, really.  But that should not be able to set the index entry mode to `100644`.)

> If `git rebase` or `git merge` throws up conflicts and changes symbolic links to plain files, is there a better way to fix the problem than deleting each file and recreating the symbolic link?

Not really, no.  You must choose *which* link (of ours vs theirs) to prefer, if either one, or even a third value (perhaps going back to the merge base version, or to yet another path).

Note that you *won't* get a merge conflict if only one "side" (ours or theirs) changes the target of the link.  In this case, either the merge-base vs ours is the same, so Git takes their change, or the merge-base vs theirs is the same, so Git takes our change—exactly as it does for any regular file.  (See [the three-way merge section of the `git read-tree` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_3_way_merge).)

Logically, `-X ours` or `-X theirs` should resolve the conflict automatically, but only in the case of a true three-way merge.  When there is an add/add conflict (because the two symlinks' targets, in the two tip commits, differ, and there's no symlink at all in the base), we never get to this point and `-X` cannot help.

Comment: You say "_you won't get a merge conflict if only one "side" (ours or theirs) changes the target of the link_". I've just checked the log for one of the problematic items. It has never existed in master. In the branch, in chronological order, it's (1) add normal file (content = target of what should be symbolic link -- don't ask me why), (2) delete item and (3) add item as symbolic link. So I can't see why the item could ever exist on both sides of the merge. I'm using Git 2.16.2 on CentOS 7.4.

Comment: Well, you're doing a rebase, which is repeated cherry-picks, so see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54542350/1256452. The add/add conflict just means "two files with the same name, I can't resolve this on my own". If it was added as a regular file and then replaced with a symlink, there may be a type-change conflict at some point as well. I have not tried this but it seems like it *should* leave one as `120000` and the other as `100644`.